# Customizable Path for file_get_contents based on Session

Tags: php, json, session, path

I dont know how to solve this issue, I have tried to look for an answer, but all I get is that I should put it between `.'filename'.`like this `file_get_contents('../jsonFIle/' . $_SESSION['nameF'] . '.json');`

I am trying to let the user input an existing json file name and it should change the context of the website from that json file. I am also a beginner and any links to how I could solve this would be appreciated

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$local_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\jsonFile';
$files = checkDir($local_dir);
$_SESSION['nameF'] = $_POST['fname'];
function checkDir($dir)
{
    return array_values(array_diff(scandir($dir) , array(
        '.',
        '..'
    )));
}
//default json file 
if (count($files) == 0 || session_id() !== '')
    {
        $jsonData = file_get_contents('../jsonFIle/Ass2News.json');
        $json = json_decode($jsonData, true);
    }
    //new updated file
    else
    {
        $jsonData = file_get_contents('../jsonFIle/' . $_SESSION['nameF'] . '.json');
        $json = json_decode($jsonData, true);
    }
?>
```

**input.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

include ("connection.php");
include ("functions.php");

$user_data = check_login($con);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Update News File</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action='../test/index.php' method='post'>
  <label for="fname">File name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="buttonS"name="apply" value="Apply">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you print the $_session, because I think on every page load the script is looking for $_POST['fname']. So are you getting the correct session if you print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: I recommend checking that the file specified by the user actually exists in that location (it should be in the $files variable). Don't trust the user-supplied data when reading resources from disk when the path includes the user-supplied data.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue, thanks to the comments, as they are not complete answers and there was some over site from my end I am going to leave the question up. I managed to solve my problem, by having if statements that checks with `isset` if the array keys are there and act accordingly. Thanks @Gurdt and @Robert for the help